# How to add delete link to recent comments block?

Tags: 7, views, blocks, comments, dashboard

I'd like to add a delete link to the 'recent comments' block on my dashboard. How can I do that? Is it possible to edit the view aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the theme_comment_block(): You can find a good tutorial here: http://www.webomelette.com/theming-comment-block-drupal-7

I instead liked to just replicate the functionality in a Views block, and then styled the block to look the same way. I felt it gave me more control, and I try to avoid hacking up core blocks.

Comment: I created a new view and added a 'Comment: delete' link. Thanks for the help!